# Notify the caller that the call is received by the callee in iOS using CallKit

Tags: swift, firebase, voip, agora.io, callkit

I am developing a VoIP audio and video calling application in iOS. Outgoing calls are working fine. I called from iOS to Android app and it's working ok. When I'm trying to call from Android to iOS or iOS to iOS, I receive the call notification and show the incoming call screen, but the problem is that the caller is not getting the notification that the callee has received the call. My receiving code is provided below

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    guard let fireCall = RealmHelper.getInstance(appRealm).getFireCallByUUID(callUUID: action.callUUID.uuidString) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print ("Audio Exception")
    }


    action.fulfill()
    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: fireCall.callUUID)!
    let answerAction: CXAnswerCallAction = CXAnswerCallAction(call: uuid)
    let transaction: CXTransaction = CXTransaction(action: answerAction)
                
    callController.request(transaction) { error in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Error!!!")
        } else {
            NSLog("Success")
        }
    }
    AppDelegate.shared.isInCall = true
  
    RealmHelper.getInstance().setCallDirection(callId: fireCall.callId, callDirection: .ANSWERED)
    reportNewIncomingCall(uuid: uuid)
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainMessage", bundle: nil)
    let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fromCallingVC") as! IncomingVC
    
    
   // vc.callingState = .ANSWERED
   // vc.callDirection = .ANSWERED
    vc.initialize(fireCall: fireCall)
    
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    AppDelegate.shared.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   
}
```

Your help and suggestion means a lot to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction)` is called by `CallKit` when you answer a call. You don't have to make a `CXAnswerCallAction` transaction inside that function, I don't know what happens in that case, but it's likely that it leads to an infinite loop.

Moreover, you don't have to call `reportNewIncomingCall(uuid: uuid)` if, in turn, it calls `reportNewIncomingCall(with UUID: UUID, update: CXCallUpdate)`. If you're answering the call, it means you already reported the new incoming call.